# Race condition in std::thread join

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio, c++11

On msvc if you try to join a thread that's not joinable it will call abort. So you have to check if the thread is joinable before calling join but this in it self is a race condition.

```
void BaseThread::join()
{
    auto thread = m_pPrivates->m_pThread;

    if (!thread)
        return;

    if (thread->get_id() != std::thread::id() && thread->joinable())
        thread->join();
}
```

Is there away to stop the run time calling abort if a thread is not joinable or a better way to do this?

.

.

.

Edit:

So this is the function that handles thread close in visual studio run time.

```
int _Thrd_join(_Thrd_t thr, int *code)
{   /* return exit code when thread terminates */
    unsigned long res;

    if (WaitForSingleObject(thr._Hnd, INFINITE) == WAIT_FAILED || GetExitCodeThread(thr._Hnd, &res) == 0)
        return (_Thrd_error);
    if (code)
        *code = (int)res;
    return (CloseHandle(thr._Hnd) == 0 ? _Thrd_error : _Thrd_success);
}
```

The last line (CloseHandle) is throwing this exception:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x7750BCEC (ntdll.dll) in desura.exe: 0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified. Which then crashes the app
```

Comment: Why do you want to join a thread that is not joinable? The management of threads must be "explicit" and clear, how do you get into a situation where your code works with random threads the code doesn't really know anything about? A stable system usually creates every threads at startup and then joins them at program exit, in "worst case" the threads sleep if the program doesn't do anything and the program knows that the threads are joinable because the threads were created as joinable... Please share more details, I'm afraid you will have to redesign this and that...

Comment: @pasztorpisti a thread becomes non joinable when it finishes thus it can finish between the check to see if its joinable and the calling of join

Comment: In case of the pthread library a joinable thread becomes non-joinable only when you join it regardless whether you join it before or after thread termination. In fact, you can, and you **have to** join a joinable thread **exactly once** if you want to avoid leaks. A joinable thread maintains the joinable part even after termination, this small piece of data contains for example the thread exit code... So you should be able to join it (but only once!) if it was created as joinable.

Comment: `a thread becomes non joinable when it finishes` False. Which part of documentation makes you believe this?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik the visual studio run time checks to see if the thread has a valid id when you call join and this calls abort if it doesnt. Its not part of the documentation but just what happens

Comment: @Lodle In case of visual studio (also in case of pthread) that isn't a thread ID but a thread handle that is still valid after thread exit until closing it.That is a handle that can still be used to refer to the previously (or still) alive thread and also to its termination status if it has already terminated. Conclusion: ID != HANDLE. A thread has a unique id **while** it is alive, but you can have many handles (even inside different processes) that refer to the very same thread object inside the kernel. This object can still exists after thread termination while you refer to it with handles.

Comment: Which part of documentation or source code makes you believe that the thread's id somehow becomes invalid when the thread finishes?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Generally a **thread id** indeed becomes invalid when the thread terminates but in this case we are talking about a **thread handle** that becomes invalid only after closing it.

Comment: @pasztorpisti: not sure what you mean by "generally", or by "we" (I, for one, was not talking about thread handles). On Windows, a thread ID remains valid (and cannot be reused) for as long as there's at least one handle referring to the thread, whether said thread is running or otherwise.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You must by right about the id and thinking it over it is logical (I indeed made a mistake here) because handles basically keep alive the thread object that of course has/keeps the id. Still, keeping only an ID as a reference in our process for long and referring to something with that ID can be risky without knowing the rules of how the api reuses released ids (maybe some apis don't reuse them). A lot of apis recycle ids with some timeouts. In contrast referring to something with handle is always safe and it is the way to go in my opinion.

Comment: @pasztorpisti: you are busy arguing a point that no one is disputing. However, I fail to see the relevance of your argument to the issue at hand. The original question is about `std::thread` class, and Visual C++'s implementation thereof. I imagine said implementation keeps whatever needs to be kept. The id in question is `std::thread::id` - whether it represents a Windows thread id, thread handle, or something else is an irrelevant implementation detail.

Answer (score 6):

It's not inherently a race condition.  A thread remains joinable until it is either joined, detached, or moved-from.  These are all things your program has control over, and if another thread is doing one of these things asynchronously to the thread you're trying to join, you obviously have to synchronize.  Usually, it's not, though, and you're the owner/manager of the thread.

Note that just because a thread finishes execution, that does not make it unjoinable.  In fact, even if you can guarantee that a thread has completed execution, you still have to join with it (or detach it, etc.) to prevent `terminate()` from being called.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22338715/race-condition-in-stdthread-join/22339968?iemail=1&noredirect=1#comment33979697_22338715

Comment: I don't see how that comment is relevant to this answer.  If a C++ implementation aborts when you join or detach a thread that hasn't yet been joined or detached, that implementation is nonconforming, and that needs to be fixed in the compiler/standard library.